# function sort don't work when symfony environment is prod

Tags: twig, symfony6

I'm using the twig function `sort` in my symfony template, this one work when my `APP_ENV=dev`but not when `APP_ENV=prod`.
This is how I use it :

```
{% for site in app.user.bailleur.sites | sort %}
 <li>
  <a href="{{ path('site', {'slug':site.slug}) }}">
   {{ site.adresse }}
  </a>
 </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Did someone know why it's doing this ?

Comment: Define: doesn't work. Is the output wrong? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Can you dump `app.user.bailleur.sites` and see the results on prod?

Comment: @DarkBee, yeah my list isn't ordered by asc when i'm using the prod env. I don't have any error

Comment: Maybe you need to clear cache in prod